# catch a "index out of range" exception of a QVector object

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I´m using a QVector to save values of a file text. I want to control  when I select a incorrect file and a "index out of range" happens. I am trying with a catch(...) but I don´t get attach the exception. is it possible attach this type of events of QObjects with try-ctach blocks?

Comment: alternatively you can use `if (index < vector.count())` to determine if you are out of range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt doesn't use exceptions, it just has asserts on out of range access.  You will need to either switch to std::vector or implement your own wrapper around QVector which throws.

Comment: std::vector also does not throw

Comment: `std::vector::at` does